# Integers seen as a continuous shape

Tags: continuity

In a popular maths book I find this sentence, in the context of an explanation of the difference between discrete and continuous, especially as regards groups:

> The group of integers is discrete; that is to say, its elements do not
>   combine into a continuous geometric shape in any natural sense.

I have no problem with the sentence in itself, within the limits of a popular exposition. I was just asking myself: Is there a “non-natural”, but non-trivial, sense in which integers can be seen as forming a continuous “geometric shape”?

Answer (score 1):

There are countably many integers ($\mathbb{Z}$) and rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$), and hence a 1-1 correspondence between the integers and the rationals. The rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so you might be able to think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a "line", and by countability also $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Perhaps a very "hole-y" line. You could also map it to the unit circle by a bijective argument with $\mathbb{Q}$ again. Let $\frac{p}{q}$ be a rational number in lowest terms. Consider the map $\frac{p}{q}\mapsto e^{2\pi ip/q}$. If I recall correctly, this is a dense subset of the unit circle. Again, this is has holes but you can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of continuity I think you're trying to express is captured by the topological concept of [connectedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). There do exist countable connected spaces (even Hausdorff ones), but most constructions are odd. If you applied something like this to $\mathbb{Z}$ there wouldn't be a good notion of distance like there is in the standard topology of $\mathbb{Z}$ (every countable [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) is disconnected).